# Modificar interfaz de una actividad de antroid studio desde java

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un par de controles en la actividad principal, estoy intentando hacer que al momento de hacer clic en un botón se cambie de posición otro control. Estoy trabajando con un ConstraintLayout. Para ejemplificar mas quiero hacer algo como:
`Boton.Position(15,15);`
Pero no se como acceder a la propiedad de la posición del control

Comment: A que te refieres con "no se como acceder a la propiedad de la posición del control" , el control de otra vista ? porque no agregas el código de lo que tratas de realizar

Comment: Una disculpa si me exprese mal, vengo de programar en aplicaciones de escritorio en C#, por lo que aun no conozco el ambiente android en su totalidad. En resumen solo quiero que al pulsar el botón, este se mueva de posición